# VS code intagrated terminal broken

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

My integrated terminal doesn't work. I have no functional terminal. I can't create new one. When I click on the plus button, nothing append. And I don't have any terminal profile in the dropdown list.
[dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcBXv.png)

I added some profiles in my settings file, but it seems they are not recognized.

```
 {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
}
```

I tried to uninstall vs code, remove all folders and reinstall vs code but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added
`"terminal.integrated.useWslProfiles": false`
to my settings and it solved my problem.

There is an issue about that on Github. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134418

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue; for now, I installed version 1.59 which fixed my problem: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59

I'd be interested in learning if there's a better fix, or if a bug report has been filed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I opened an issue on github. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133661